# Methods for binary linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, binary-variable

I have an LP problem (linear objective with eq and ineq constraints) in binary variables.

Except for the objective, all the coefficients are integer, mostly in {-1,0,1}. Maybe the objective coeff could be discretized.

I usually use an MI solver (gurobi). Since it solves a moderate problem in my case under a second, I suspect that it may have a special structure that permits employing a different specialized method that will be faster. Can you suggest other methods to solve my problem?

More details in a duplicate question:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4504572/methods-for-binary-linear-programming/4505035

---

@worldsmithhelper suggests (in the comments) to test a problem on all solvers using

https://neos-server.org/neos/solvers/index.html

I'm considering automating it. I'm using yalmip, which can export the following formats:

https://yalmip.github.io/tags/#export-and-import

This can be wrapped in an XML and sent via a python client (in a loop for each solver):

https://neos-guide.org/users-guide/neos-interfaces/#xml

Comment: Link only questions don't self-document and can't be easily refined. Please post an actual question.

Comment: I must say that as a new user who first post a question on this board, down-voting my question along with an incoherent explanation isn't too friendly.

Comment: @Zoher: I can certainly see that. Try to keep in mind that this isn't commentary on _you_, it's commentary on the question _as currently stated _. StackExchange has great answers because we work hard to have great questions.

Comment: @Zoher: To make a better question for OR you need to include the text of the question on this site. A link to your question is not enough. It also helps (I peeked at the link) if your question contains question marks to make it really clear what you're asking.

Comment: You are saying that I'm not stupid, it's just my questions; thanks, I feel better now :)     I edited my question to include a question mark.

Comment: It's now clearer what you're asking. I'd still suggest scraping this question (there's a delete button) and trying again with a new question that doesn't link to external material or your other question. If you search for how to ask a good question on StackExchange, you'll find guides.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. However: 1. Sometime people need someone to put a mirror in front of them. 2. It's one thing to write a self-contained question. It's quite another to insist on being secluded and not look at other links. I don't condone it.

Comment: This is great. I have nothing to add, I just wanted to be part of the conversation.

Comment: Without seeing your problem formulation it is impossible to hazard a guess. A general piece of advice is that you upload an example problem with no proprietary data to NEOS and compare how all MILP solvers perform. In one case i had SCIP turn in a correct solution in 20min while all others timed out after 4 hours.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with NEOS, this is useful. See my edit if you have tips on automation.

Comment: Cross posted on Math.SE (as noted by OP): [Methods for binary linear programming](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4504572/572874)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be classified as a [0-1 integer linear program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming). Problems in this class are NP-hard in general, even when the coefficients are all integers and there is no objective function.

There are specific subclasses that are easier to solve. For example, [integral linear programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Integral_linear_programs) can be solved in continuous variables and will still produce a 0-1 solution. The most common way of proving that a polytope is integral is through total unimodularity.

Without further information, using a mixed-integer programming solver seems like your best bet. It is not surprising that small instances are solvable while larger ones are not: in general you would expect the solution time of NP-hard problems to increase exponentially. Your polytope is probably not integral: if it was the solver would detect that after solving the root relaxation in node 0 and terminate quickly.

If you share more information about the problem structure, we may be able to provide more help.

Comment: It was more of a general, theoretical question. I'm not sure about my problem structure (although I can share a specific instance of it in a .mps), and I'd like to through everything at it. More details of what I referred to are in the link to the math forum.