# Compare optimization packages on a specific problem

Tags: optimization

It was suggested that I compare between the popular optimization packages on my specific problem:

[Methods for binary linear programming](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/8822/methods-for-binary-linear-programming)

I started working on it, and I'm finding myself diving into the AMPL doc to find the parameters for each solver just to print the time, e.g.

```
option gurobi_options 'outlev=1';
option cplex_options 'outlev=2 timing=1 tunedisplay=3';
option copt_options 'logging=1';
```

Then, I'll need to write a python client to interface with NEOS, parse the results, and print a nice table.

I'm thinking to myself again, surely someone has done that already, or there must be an easier solution?

Maybe it's not necessary to compare all the solvers, and the three that I started with should be the best for linear programming in this case? The general benchmark link in the comments can give a hint about that, but maybe someone can summarize from experience and say "don't bother with the others."

---

Looks like the AMPL exporter of yalmip doesn't scale well, and I'll need some help in:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73319460/gams-solve-a-canonical-lp-model

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73319510/ampl-solve-a-canonical-lp-model

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73319936/pyomo-solve-a-canonical-lp-model

Is there a format that is recognized by NEOS and supports matrix algebra?

Gurbi matlab has gurobi_write(), which can export to MPS. However, the file size is 192MB. It can also compress it and generate .bz2, and the file size is down to 22MB.

NEOS doesn't accept compressed files(??), but even if it did:

> NEOS encountered an error in the submission:  Files must be smaller
> than 16777216 bytes.

...?

Comment: Would you see Hans Mittelmann's [benchmarks](http://plato.asu.edu/bench.html)?

Comment: Benchmarks can give you a general trend. I added a clarification that I'd like to make the comparison on my specific problem.

Comment: Using NEOS for benchmarking is unlikely to produce reliable results. Since the problems might be on different computers that addition might run other jobs.

Comment: Good to know. It means that I'll need to try it a few times over some period. Either there would be some consistent trend, or it would be useless.

Comment: Could you install all solvers and run these benchmarks on your own machine?

Comment: There is an exception for the benchmarks - if a solver absolutely destroys your problem compared to the others (e.g. it's 10,000 times faster)  that's beyond any fluctuations introduced by the environment.

Comment: Note that better formulations can (sometimes) make more difference than better solvers.